# Build Failure with maven sure fire plugin error on Jenkins: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jenkins

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project HawthorneEffectAutomation: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton && /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-1.amzn2.0.3.x86_64/bin/java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton/target/surefire/surefirebooter14653655313054336893.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton/target/surefire/surefire15702145916035405804tmp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton/target/surefire/surefire_083360849272140865tmp
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton/pom.xml to org.example/HawthorneEffectAutomation/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HawthorneEffectAutomation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
[CucumberReport] Using Cucumber Reports version 5.7.1
[CucumberReport] JSON report directory is ""
[CucumberReport] Copied 8 properties files from workspace "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton" to reports directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HE_HQ_Automaton/builds/143/cucumber-html-reports/.cache"
[CucumberReport] Copied 2 files from workspace "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton" to reports directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HE_HQ_Automaton/builds/143/cucumber-html-reports/.cache"
[CucumberReport] Processing 2 json files:
[CucumberReport] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HE_HQ_Automaton/builds/143/cucumber-html-reports/.cache/target/cucumber-reports/report.json
[CucumberReport] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HE_HQ_Automaton/builds/143/cucumber-html-reports/.cache/target/cucumber.json
[CucumberReport] Missing report result - the report was not successfully completed
[CucumberReport] Build status is left unchanged
Finished: FAILURE
```

I did check the plugin version and dependency version and all are up to date and matching with each other